# How to stop my lumia 620 from passing the ringing to the bluetooth headset

Tags: bluetooth

I have the Nokia Lumia 620 wp8 phone and I've recently bought a bluetooth headset(nokia bh-100).
The problem is that when I am receiving a call now, after 3 seconds the phone stops ringing and passes the ringing to the headphone.
That way I have missed quite some calls because I did not heard the 3 sec ringing.
Any ideas on how to fix that?
Thank you.

Comment: Does it do this when the headset is off?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: At the risk of asking a dumb question; why do you leave the headset turned on, when not using it? It seems the phone does what you want when the headset is turned off; and also what you want when yuo're using the headset?

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason turning off the headset is impractical or undesirable, you can also just turn off the Bluetooth on the phone (though that will disconnect *all* BT devices, not just headsets but also things like fitness watches and such, until you turn it on again). I have Bluetooth in the "quick actions" buttons on my phone, so I can switch it on or off with just a swipe down from the top and then a single tap.

Answer (score 0):

**How to resolve this**

Turn off the headset.